# Modem Manager not detecting Qualcomm USB modem on Manjaro KDE

Tags: networking, manjaro, modem

I use Manjaro KDE and I’ve been trying to use my Qualcomm modem on it,
but the modem manager-gui is not detecting it.

Here is the result of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:1135 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also here is the result of `mmcli -L`:

```
No modems were found
```

`sudo systemctl status ModemManager.service` result:

```
Jul 17 20:46:35 rasheed-81hl ModemManager[488]: [base-manager] couldn’t check support for device ‘/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/0000:02:00.0’: not supp>
Jul 17 20:46:35 rasheed-81hl ModemManager[488]: [base-manager] couldn’t check support for device ‘/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.1/0000:03:00.0’: not supp>
Jul 17 20:48:45 rasheed-81hl ModemManager[488]: [base-manager] couldn’t check support for device ‘/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/usb1/1-3’: not supporte>
```

I have tried some solutions I saw here and those ones on the Arch wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later checked the Arch Linux wiki where I saw [a solution](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mobile_broadband_modem). 
I was prompted to whitelist my device using [the ModemManager filter](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ModemManager/api/latest/ref-overview-modem-filter.html). 
Make sure you change your vendor and product IDs on the script. 
To determine these, run `lsusb` in your terminal. In my case, I have

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 5986:1135 Acer, Inc Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The entry for the modem is

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75
```

So my vendor and product IDs are `05c6` and `6000`, respectively.